# How do I get cromwell to create soft-links?

Tags: wdl

The file system I'm running on doesn't allow the creation of hard-links.  Cromwell is trying to create hard-links to directories, and when that fails, it's copying them.  Which is leading to disk quota errors.

Is there a way that I can simply tell cromwell "try soft links first"?  Without creating a whole config file?

Comment: Hi could you tell us what your disk quota is please?

Comment: @Michael 4.9 TB.  Which my pipeline fills up shortly before it's supposed to finish

Comment: It is possible to [set configuration values via the command line](https://cromwell.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Configuring/#configuration-via-command-line). I haven't tried this, though (and it will probably make you command pretty long...)

Comment: @DavyCats we broke down and created a config file.  Problem is that for some reason cromwell insists on creating "<dirname>.tmp" directories with complete copies of the working directory